# Avoid recreating activity when Dark theme was changed outside of app

Tags: java, android, themes

When the user changes the system theme from the notification menu, my activity getting recreated and data is loaded again, which is not my app's requirement.

Is it possible to prevent a system theme change from affecting my application in this way?

Comment: "it is getting recreated" -- change in dark mode is a configuration change, as is rotating the screen, changing the locale in Settings, entering or exiting split-screen mode, etc. Your app needs to be able to handle configuration changes. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes).

Comment: I have implemented onConfigurationChanged method as is shown in the documentation. But, it doesn't handle the theme configuration change(Tested on MI 8).

Comment: Note that `onConfigurationChanged()` is only called if you have `android:configChanges` in the manifest entry and that the particular type of configuration change that you try is in the `android:configChanges` list. It is also possible that Xiaomi is doing something different than what we see in standard Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't stop the theme change instead store your data in viewModels.

The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations or theme change.

Have a look : [viewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: However, I have several fragments inside my main activity. I shouldn't let dark theme recreate it, not only fragments and DialogFragments too.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below in Manifest file

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="uiMode"> //★★★★add this line★★★★

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Sources:
https://proandroiddev.com/daynight-applying-dark-mode-without-recreating-your-app-c8a62d51092d

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33166343)

Comment: This solution works fine but it is better to implement dark theme in your application and let the Android system recreate your activity to reload activity with new configurations.